# C++ MultiThreading block main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I try to make a timeout in a C++ program:

```
  ...
void ActThreadRun(TimeOut *tRun)
{
    tRun->startRun();
}
  ...
void otherFunction()
{
TimeOut *tRun = new TimeOut();
std::thread t1 (ActThreadRun, tRun);
t1.join();    

    while(tRun->isTimeoutRUN())
    {
       manageCycles();
    }
 }
  ...
```

The timeout is done after 3 seconds, and `tRun->isTimeoutRUN()` changes its state.

But if I "`join`" the thread, I block the program, so it waits 3 seconds before continuing, so it never goes into my while loop...

But if I don't "`join`" the thread, the thread never times out, and `tRun->isTimeoutRUN()` never changes, so it runs infinitely.

I'm not good with threads, so I'm asking your help because I don't understand the tutorials on this in C++.

Comment: Try adding a memory barrier in the while loop. The compiler could be putting the value into a register

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new C++11 facilities

```
// thread example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread

void sleep() 
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );//this makes this thread sleep for 2s
}

int main()
{
      std::thread timer(sleep);// launches the timer
      int a=2;//this dummy instruction can be executed even if the timer thread did not finish 
      timer.join();            // wait unil timer finishes, ie until the sleep function is done
      std::cout<<"Time expired!";
      return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But I had to do somethings between the join and the std::cout, a While loop, which the break is a method call in my thread ...

Comment: if you had something to do before the join and the cout<<"Time expired!" then add it to the sleep function, after the std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );//this makes this thread sleep for 2s. then you will: start the thread, run the timer, do what you want to do and then print the cout. does that solve your problem?

Comment: The Thread I want to do is just a timeOut for my program. So I can do so work and when the timeOut is here, it's stop the loop. But When I call Join it's always block the main thread, so I can't continue to work, even with your method

Comment: then you can start a thread and call tthe timeout inside. the main thread will not be affected then